# what‘s’ the meaning of metrics trough rest api in Apache Spark

Tags: rest, apache-spark, metrics

what's the meaning of the metrics that i get from the `url/applications/[app-id]/stages`?

when input bytes is 0, why shuffle read bytes is not 0?
How do executor run time & CPU time calculate?

```
 "executorRunTime" : 137,
  "executorCpuTime" : 45102739,
  "inputBytes" : 0,
  "inputRecords" : 0,
  "outputBytes" : 0,
  "outputRecords" : 0,
  "shuffleReadBytes" : 14453,
```